# Maven compiler plugin - send parameters to javac (classpath or cp)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

Is it possible to send arguments to javac through maven compiler plugin?

I want to set three classpaths as a argument to javac but maven returns

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project wplex-frameworks: Compilation failure
[ERROR] javac: invalid flag: classpath=*:.
[ERROR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac</executable>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>classpath=*:.</arg>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>x/y/z/**</exclude>
        </excludes> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have tried so far classpath=*:. , -classpath=*:. , -classpath *:.

The other arguments are fine.

Comment: First why do you like to set `classpath` apart from that classpath options looks like this: `-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>`.  Furthermore why have defined an absolute path in your configuration and why not using the classpath which is created by Maven? Apart from that an option `-options` does not exist? This is also true for `-path` ? and why you like to exclude something?

Comment: The absolute path is just an bad minimal example. I need to use very specific set of jars located in three separated directories as classpath + java 1.8 to compile the project. The reason for exclusion is that I am migrating an ant legacy project to maven, and there are some things I need to reproduce from there (for now), one of that things is that a specific compilation does not use some classes (dependencies problems maybe, I do not know). I did not try the -options and -path flags, but I think it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I will do the right way and install local dependencies and use <dependencies> tag. (I was in a dark place just cloning an ant build to maven). Thanks.

Comment: It might be very helpful to install a repository in your corporate environment and deploy the needed artifacts there .... so you can consume it network wide...

Comment: It is exactly what I will do :D thank you.